# CDT IASTNode getRawSignature after preprocessor

Tags: java, abstract-syntax-tree, eclipse-cdt

In CDT core plugin, there is a method `getRawSignature` of interface `IASTNode` that was described as:

```
Returns the raw signature of the IASTNode before it is processed by the preprocessor.
Example:
#define ONE 1
int x=ONE; // getRawSignature() for this declaration would return "int x=ONE;"
```

But I want to get the String signature **after** the node is processed by the preprocessor
In the above example, the expected string is: `int x=1`
How to get this string? I have looked at some other methods, but no one can.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Great question!

The first thing to note is that, at no point during CDT's processing does code exist in the form of a preprocessed string.

The processing flow is this:

```
   Unpreprocessed string
-> [Lexer]
-> Unpreprocessed token stream
-> [Preprocessor]
-> Preprocessed token stream
-> [Parser]
-> Abstract syntax tree
```

Notice that in preprocessed form, the code only exists as a token stream, not as a string.

That said, if you had the preprocessed token stream, you could probably use it to construct a preprocessed string.

Unfortunately, I'm not aware of an easy way to obtain preprocessed tokens, and [this mailing list thread](https://dev.eclipse.org/mhonarc/lists/cdt-dev/msg30188.html) suggests there may not be one.

The closest I think we can come is to re-preprocess the file, and thereby obtain preprocessed token stream for the entire file. This can be done by invoking `AbstractCLikeLanguage.createScanner()` to obtain an `IScanner` (it's a protected method, so you'd need to derive from `GCCLanguage` or `GPPLanguage` to access it), and calling `IScanner.nextToken()` repeatedly to obtain the preprocessed tokens.

That still doesn't quite give you what you want, since you want preprocessed tokens corresponding to a particular AST node. I *believe* you can compute this by comparing the offset and length of the preprocessed tokens (obtained using `IToken.getOffset()` and `IToken.getLength()`) to the offset and length of the AST node (obtained using `ASTNode.getOffset()` and `ASTNode.getLength()`), which I believe are in the same numbering space.

Comment: When does the Indexer get active and can it be extended, too?